# Splitting a string into a Stash list?

Tags: stash, csv

For an EE3 site, I'd like to split a CSV or pipe delimited string (i.e. `avi,david,sam` or maybe `avi|david|sam`) and have each segment added to a Stash list.

I've looked at [BBD Stringer](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/bbd-stringer) ($6) on Devot-ee thinking I might be able to use it to break up the string and then stash each value in a list but it seems to be a bit more basic: that it just breaks the string apart but not as tags which could be passed into an `{exp:stash:set_list}` tag pair.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used BBD Stringer, but have used [Low List](https://github.com/low/low_list) to help with this. You can do something like:

```
{exp:stash:set_list
    name="XXX" 
    parse_tags="yes"
}
    {exp:low_list:each items="north|east|south|west" as="individual_direction"}
        {stash:direction}{individual_direction}{/stash:direction}
    {/exp:low_list:each}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

*By the way, MANY thanks to Croxton & Low (attorneys?) for both add-ons.*

Comment: Went a different direction in terms of handling this data but this answer would have definitely gotten me where I needed to be. Bookmarked for future use. Thanks!